# LEFT JOIN in MySQL using multiple ON conditions

Tags: mysql

I know how to do a LEFT JOIN in MySQL with a single conditional or with using WHERE key IS NULL, but how do you do it when you have multiple conditions in your ON statement?  I have an invoice table that contains an Order Number and Invoice Date.  I also have a ship table that contains an Order Number and Ship Date.  I want to return any items from the invoice table where there is NOT a corresponding record in the ship table.  For example...

```
invoice table:

InvoiceNum  OrderNum  InvoiceDate
106433        136365      2011-10-03
111888        136365      2012-06-19

ship table:

OrderNum   ShipDate
136365       2012-06-19
```

I want to write a query that will return just invoice number 106433 from the invoice table.  Does someone know how best to do that.  I am joining other tables into the query, but this is the one that I'm having trouble figuring out.  Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have [multiple conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in your `ON` clause using `AND`, `OR`, etc.

```
select i.InvoiceNum
from invoice  i
left outer join ship s on i.OrderNum = s.OrderNum  
    and i.InvoiceDate = s.ShipDate
where s.OrderNum is null
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b71df/5)

Comment: Excellent!  That is exactly what I needed!  Thanks!  My problem was I was trying to match by a date range in the JOIN clause.  I didn't need to do that there...only in the WHERE clause.  When I did the date check like in your example, and put the NULL check in the WHERE clause, it worked exactly the way I needed it to.